# Disassociate Sublime with batch files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, sublime-text-2

Windows user - I made the mistake of associating a batch file with Sublime so each time I open it, instead of running, it opens in Sublime

I have not access to the command prompt (hence the reason to use batch files) or to edit the registry (work laptop, locked down)

How would I reverse this so double clicking the batch file runs it instead of opening in Sublime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.cmd` which is the same thing as `.bat`
(see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)).

If you can run as Administrator, you could restore the `.bat`
association by running a `.cmd` file containing the following command:

```
assoc .bat=batfile
```

Comment: Thanks - this works - unfortunately some startup scripts are .bat so can't be amended and they just end up opening in Sublime